# how to use the current user for other operation in react project

Tags: reactjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I'm new to react.js. I've created an application in which I'm using firebase google auth provider for signin purpose. I've also used the firebase-ui for signin component. My problem is I cann't find any reference about how to use the current logged in user for other opertions like insert a data, or view existing data in my entire app even with authentication on every page refresh or new tab open. Even keep the user logged in if he not done signout.

I want some blogs to follow and if possible can i get a overall idea about how to solve this situation or any sample project link having this complete reference.

I've followed this  [url](https://www.robinwieruch.de/complete-firebase-authentication-react-tutorial/)  as my project structure.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at this firebase doc: https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/manage-users

It looks simple to try this:
`var user = firebase.auth().currentUser`

Also React itself won't store this behavior unless you set it in the state somewhere.

Comment: unfortunately, I'm not sure which methods are best in terms of making relationships between your firebase signin and your app. I'm more experienced with having a Users table in my database.

Comment: I'm printing the user data using currentUser, what I've seen is that in case of page route I'm able to get the user data if the user is logged in. But in case of page reload I'm not getting the data initially. But once I route to another component and also come back to the previous component (where the user data is printed) using routes I'm getting the data.